# How can i tell if my connectionStrings section is encrypted or not?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, encryption, connection-string, app-config

I have followed Microsoft's instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files) in order to encrypt my connection strings for my application. I have opted to move my connection strings to their own configuration file, connections.config. My code is as posted below (bottom of page) - nearly identical to the snippets provided by Microsoft. After performing the operations, the command: `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Protected={0}", connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected))` prints `True`, indicating the operation was successful.

However, Microsoft states that "**The following configuration file fragment shows the connectionStrings section after it has been encrypted:**"

```
configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">  
  <EncryptedData>  
    <CipherData>  
      <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAH2... </CipherValue>  
    </CipherData>  
  </EncryptedData>
```

This does not appear to be true in my case. Despite printing `True` when asking if my `sectionInformation.IsProtected`, Both my app.config and my connections.config files remain unchanged when visually inspecting them. This leads me to my questions:

1. Does the description of my problem indicate that in fact my section is not protected after all?
2. Why is `sectionInformation.IsProtected` printing `True`, but no `<EncryptedData>` attributes have been added to my `sectionInformation`?
3. If you carefully read Microsoft's instructions in the link above, they provide explanations for creating both your own connections.config file outside of app.config, as well as encrypting your connections section. However, *they do not explicitly say that following their instructions for encrypting connectionStrings section will do so in the external configuration file, connections.config as well*. Is the attribute tag in app.config, `<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config" />`, sufficient to ensure this behavior?
4. How do I test that my application's connection strings are indeed encrypted correctly, other than a MessageBox printing the `IsProtected` property?

**NOTE**

1. *This is NOT an ASP.Net application, this is a Winforms application*
2. I have tested the above with my connectionStrings in both their own connections.config file, as well as within app.config file, and the result is the same.

The relevant sections of my code are posted below:

```
*app.config*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- ... -->
    </configSections>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <!-- ... -->
    </system.diagnostics>
    <userSettings>
        <!-- ... -->
    </userSettings>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config" />
</configuration>

*connections.config*

<connectionStrings>
  <!--Manhattan Connection-->
  <add name="MANHATTAN"
       connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=False" />
  <add name="DENVER"
     connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=False" />
  <add name="DESMOINES"
     connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=False" />
</connectionStrings>

*The connection source code*

Private Sub ToggleConfigurationEncryption(ByVal executableName As String)
    Try
        Dim configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(executableName)
        Dim connectionStringsSection = configManager.GetSection("connectionStrings")
        If connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then
            connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection()
        Else
            connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
        End If
        configManager.Save()
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Protected={0}", connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected))
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionController.LogException(ex)
        ExceptionController.DisplayException(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is happening in your `if` statement.

```
If connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then
        connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection()
...
```

This example shows how to toggle between encrypting and decrypting. In the code posted by you, you're simply decrypting the file if it's already encrypted. Your code should be something like this:

```
If (Not connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected) Then
    connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
End If
```

You only want to encrypt if the file has not been encrypted.  Don't worry about decrypting the file and trying to read. It will automatically decrypt it for you.

I don't see the how you're calling the `ToggleConfigurationEncryption` method. You need to pass the correct name of the output config file.  After you launch your app (if in debug mode) you can go to project directory in `bin\debug` folder and look for your `connections.config` file. When you open it you'll see that it's encrypted.